# Angular fixture debugElement NULL

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-material, karma-jasmine

While doing debugElement.query, I'm getting `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null`.

My html code:

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="standard" id="my-searchBox">
      <input matInput [formControl]="filterBox"              
            id="filterBox-input">
    </mat-form-field>

    <div class="mat-table-elevated-wrapper mat-elevation-z4">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th class="table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                    <input matInput [formControl]="nameFilter" id="name-input">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let elem">
                  elem.name
                </td>
            </ng-container>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And I add the following code in the unit test:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CallLogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let myList = [];
    let entry = getDummyEntry();
    myList.push(entry);
    component.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(myList);
    component.dataSource.data = myList;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('verify filter changes', () => {

    let filterBoxInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#filterBox-input'));
    filterBoxInput.nativeElement.value = 'dummy';
    filterBoxInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.boxValue).toBe('dummy');

    // works till here, issue causes on below line

    let nameInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#name-input')); --> null
    nameInput.nativeElement.value = 'dummyName';
    nameInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.name).toBe('dummyName');
  });
```

Then I get the error for nameInput:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null

I'm also adding some dummy data to the mat table datasource. Still getting the issue for nameInput.

What could be causing the issue?

Comment: This message means your variable `filterBoxInput` is null, looks like this line didn't work`fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#filterBox-input'));` and didn't find your input with the id #filterBox-input. Please provide a stackblitz in order to reproduce your bug.

Comment: @Yvan filterBox-input is found, but name-input is not found

Comment: Ok so, it's because your input didn't exist, did you fill the datasource of the table ? in order to create the content of the table, th tr ...   You have to create a datasource in your table. make sure component.datasource is filled.

Comment: @Yvan I tried to fill the datasource, please see the updated code in beforeEach. But I'm still getting the error

Comment: Can you check output of `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('mat-form-field')` ? and ``fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#name-input')` .  and double check `datasource` by doing `console.log` just before these conditions are checked.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek I did console.log. `component.datasource` had a value. `querySelector('mat-form-field')` had value mat-form-field#my-searchBox, and `querySelector('#name-input')` had value null

Comment: It's because you have the element with `id="name-input"` inside an ng-container.  From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue): "The Angular <ng-container> is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM."  If it's not in the DOM, then you won't be able to get it with `querySelector()`.

Comment: @dmcgrandle Thank you. So is there any this test case can be written?